# How to display character field in openERP 7.0?

Tags: odoo

> How to display character field in openERP 7.0?

Comment: How to display character field in openERP 7.0 with label?

Comment: you can simply display it like 6.1 <field name="fieldname" /> it take automatically take label from your field what ever you have given in py file for ex.name = fields.char('Emp Name',size=64) it dispaly a lable Emp Name.

Answer (score 0):

```
> For Class:
> 
> '<field_name>': fields.char('Text', size=Char Size, translate=True,
> required=True)
> 
> For View:
> 
> <field name="<field_name>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a text field in python file as follows.

```
'field_name': fields.text('Field Label'),
```

And then add it in your xml view as follows

```
<field name="field_name" />
```

It will display the label as 'Field Label'. If you want to change this label again, then use this label attribute.

```
<label for="field_name" string="New Label" />
```

It will display 'New Label' in view.